# Fb page post to another fb page with graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

is there any way that I post to my partners facebook page as my fb page? I didn't find any solution for that - I know how to post to page via graph api, but it seems that page-to-page feauture is blocked.

Anyone?

Leo

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: I'm not sure it's a bug or by design. I already report a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/285031211633194 related to link type post at may 8 2013**

Let's say you are the admin fanpage called "Iptv",so you want to post to fanpage "coca-cola".

The first step is get Page Access Token via /me/accounts API. (Put this Page Access Token inside Graph API explorer's access token field for test.)

Then you can't simply do http POST request to PAGE_ID/feed with message parameter, because you would get error message:

[image]

What you can do is post a 'link' type post, then you're able to post as page.

[image]

**Success post to coca-cola page as another page called 'Iptv':**

[image]